# Django - How do I recreate or import the django admin green plus sign for adding new related instances?

Tags: django

For example I have a model like this:

```
class Wheel(models.Model):
    wheel = models.CharField(max_length=20)

class Vehicle(models.Model):
    wheel = models.ForeignKey(Wheel)
```

When I make a new Vehicle, I want the green plus sign to appear beside my
wheel field and allow me to add new instances of Wheel. I'm quite new to django so I don't know if it's possible. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the widget `django.contrib.admin.widgets.RelatedFieldWidgetWrapper`. It's the widget used by Django Admin to add the functional '+' mark, [here](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/admin/options.py#L120).
In order to use the widget in your custom form, you need to provide the `admin_site` argument that serves the adding page of the Wheel.

Comment: Hey -- stupid question. Where do I get the `admin_site` from?

Comment: @Neal its [the `admin.site` typically](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.AdminSite), often see in your `admin.py` files, if you have not customized the `AdminSite`

Answer (score 5):

If you are implementing your form outside the admin section, you'll need a custom widget wrapper similar to django.contrib.admin.widgets.RelatedFieldWidgetWrapper. Example on usage:

```
from .models import Owner
from .widgets import AddAnotherWidgetWrapper   # our custom widget wrapper

class PickOwnerForm(forms.Form):
    owner = forms.ModelChoiceField(
    queryset=Owner.objects.all().order_by('name'),
    widget=AddAnotherWidgetWrapper(forms.Select(),Owner, )
)
```

In your implementation, substitute 'Owner' with the model you are linking to.

You can find the custom widget wrapper along with a full example at - https://gist.github.com/ebrelsford/5263306

Answer (score 0):

By default, only fields that have "editable=True" will be added to the admin pages:

[ModelAdmin.fields](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.fields)

**models.py**

```
class Wheel(models.Model):
    wheel = models.CharField(max_length=20, editable=True)

class Vehicle(models.Model):
    wheel = models.ForeignKey(Wheel, editable=True)
```

Comment: Thanks! But what if I want to do this outside of the admin form? Is that possible?

Comment: This is not the admin form. This is your model definition

Comment: Yeah, so how do I display that green plus sign on my custom form?

Comment: You didn't mention you were working with a custom form. Is the Vehicle class already showing up in your admin, but simply missing the wheels field?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of how to use the `RelatedFieldWidgetWrapper` **outside of the admin** together with an `AutocompleteSelect` (can of course also just be a `Select`). This also shows how to include js, css that might be needed depending on where this is included:

```py
from django import forms
from django.contrib.admin import site as admin_site
from django.contrib.admin import widgets

class MyModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        db_field = self.instance._meta.get_field("related")

        self.fields["related"] = ModelChoiceField(
            self.fields["related"].queryset,
            widget=AutocompleteSelect(db_field, admin_site),
        )
        self.fields["related"].widget = widgets.RelatedFieldWidgetWrapper(
            widget=self.fields["related"].widget,
            rel=db_field.remote_field,
            admin_site=admin_site,
        )

    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = ("related",)

    class Media:
        js = [
            "admin/js/jquery.init.js",
            "admin/js/admin/RelatedObjectLookups.js",
        ]
        css = {"all": ("admin/css/forms.css",)}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a bespoke custom `forms.ModelForm` by looping through each field. If a field is of the classes `forms.ModelChoiceField` or `forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField`, you can append the `contrib.admin.widgets.RelatedFieldWidgetWrapper` to such field by providing the correct inputs.

```py
from django.contrib.admin import site as admin_site
from django.contrib.admin.widgets import RelatedFieldWidgetWrapper
from django import forms
import .models

class RelativeForm(forms.ModelForm)
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(RelativeForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        for field_name, field in self.fields.items():
            if isinstance(field, (forms.ModelChoiceField, forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField)): 
               field.widget = RelatedFieldWidgetWrapper( 
                   self.field.widget,
                   self.instance._meta.get_field(field_name).remote_field,            
                   admin_site,
                   )


class VehicleForm(RelativeForm):
     class Meta:
          model = models.Vehicle
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).